# For LOOP with group by insert into ORA-06550 Column NOT ALLOWED HERE error

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am having problem with writing procedure for insert into table that has select statement with group by in for loop.

Here is look at my code:

```
begin
  FOR R IN (WITH
     bez_oib
          AS
     (SELECT a.EXT_ACCOUNT_ID,
             a.ACCOUNT_ID,
             c.NAME,
             c.ATTRIBUTE_VALUE_1     AS oib3
       FROM MD_ACCOUNTS a, MD_CONTACTS c
      WHERE     a.ACCOUNT_ID = c.REFERENCE_ID
            AND c.REFERENCE_TYPE_ID = 2
            AND c.CONTACT_TYPE_ID = 1
            AND a.EXT_ACCOUNT_ID IN (  SELECT a.EXT_ACCOUNT_ID
                                         FROM MD_ACCOUNTS a
                                     GROUP BY a.EXT_ACCOUNT_ID
                                       HAVING COUNT (DISTINCT a.account_id) > 1)
            AND c.ATTRIBUTE_VALUE_1 IS NULL),
     sa_oib
         AS
     (SELECT a.EXT_ACCOUNT_ID,
             a.ACCOUNT_ID,
             c.NAME,
             c.ATTRIBUTE_VALUE_1     AS oib2
       FROM MD_ACCOUNTS a, MD_CONTACTS c
      WHERE     a.ACCOUNT_ID = c.REFERENCE_ID
            AND c.REFERENCE_TYPE_ID = 2
            AND c.CONTACT_TYPE_ID = 1
            AND a.EXT_ACCOUNT_ID IN (  SELECT a.EXT_ACCOUNT_ID
                                         FROM MD_ACCOUNTS a
                                     GROUP BY a.EXT_ACCOUNT_ID
                                       HAVING COUNT (DISTINCT a.account_id) > 1)
            AND c.ATTRIBUTE_VALUE_1 IS NOT NULL)
SELECT BEZ_OIB.EXT_ACCOUNT_ID as SIFRA_KK,
     BEZ_OIB.ACCOUNT_ID as a,
     BEZ_OIB.NAME as c ,
     BEZ_OIB.oib3 as b ,
     SUM (IH1.REST_TO_PAY)     AS PREOSTALI_DUG_BEZ_OIB,
     SA_OIB.EXT_ACCOUNT_ID as s,
     SA_OIB.ACCOUNT_ID as d,
     SA_OIB.NAME as e,
     SA_OIB.oib2 as f,
     SUM (IH2.REST_TO_PAY)     AS PREOSTALI_DUG_SA_OIB
FROM bez_oib,
     sa_oib,
     CA_INVOICE_HEADERS IH1,
     CA_INVOICE_HEADERS IH2
 WHERE     bez_oib.EXT_ACCOUNT_ID = sa_oib.EXT_ACCOUNT_ID
     AND bez_oib.NAME <> sa_oib.name
     AND BEZ_OIB.ACCOUNT_ID = IH1.ACCOUNT_ID(+)
     AND SA_OIB.ACCOUNT_ID = IH2.ACCOUNT_ID(+)
     AND BEZ_OIB.EXT_ACCOUNT_ID NOT IN ('30150151054',
                                        '33671110205',
                                        '31841000148',
                                        '31840520300',
                                        '30200150216',
                                        '33670011076')
GROUP BY BEZ_OIB.EXT_ACCOUNT_ID,
     BEZ_OIB.ACCOUNT_ID,
     BEZ_OIB.NAME,
     BEZ_OIB.oib3,
     SA_OIB.EXT_ACCOUNT_ID,
     SA_OIB.ACCOUNT_ID,
     SA_OIB.NAME,
     SA_OIB.oib2) 
     LOOP
insert into dun_exception (ID, TYPE, VALUE, ACTION, VALID_FROM, VALID_TO, STATE, NOTE, CREATED_BY, CREATE_DATE, MODIFIED_BY, MODIFY_DATE, PROC_NAME, BUYER_ID, REASON) values (DUN_EXCEPTION_SEQ.nextval,'BUYER_ID',r.sifra_kk,null,date'2021-10-26', date'2022-12-31',1,'Jedna ŠK, različit naziv, ima OIB - nema OIB', 'sbelcic',sysdate,null,null,nul,null,null);
END LOOP;
END;
```

After I try to execute it I get the following error:

```
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 66, column 351:
PL/SQL: ORA-00984: column not allowed here
```

Column in particular error refers to last line of `group by` statement.

The code should insert values into table but it isn't working.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's `nul`, Stjepane.

```
<snip>    
VALUES (DUN_EXCEPTION_SEQ.NEXTVAL,
     'BUYER_ID',
     r.sifra_kk,
     NULL,
     DATE '2021-10-26',
     DATE '2022-12-31',
     1,
     'Jedna ŠK, različit naziv, ima OIB - nema OIB',
     'sbelcic',
     SYSDATE,
     NULL,
     NULL,
     nul,                  --> here
     NULL,
     NULL);
```